# Skipping until specific instructions in GDB

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb

I have some assembly that I'm trying to debug in GDB. More specifically, I'm trying to look at what values are being compared throughout the program, but there are a lot of instructions that I don't what to step through. Is there a way to simply run until I hit a specific type of instruction, like a cmp? For example:

```
0x08048eaf <+98>:    mov    %ecx,%edx
0x08048eb1 <+100>:   sub    (%eax),%edx
0x08048eb3 <+102>:   mov    %edx,(%eax)
0x08048eb5 <+104>:   add    $0x4,%eax
0x08048eb8 <+107>:   cmp    %ebx,%eax
0x08048eba <+109>:   jne    0x8048eaf <func+98>
```

This is just a simple loop, but I don't want to have to step through all the other commands just to look at the compare statement. I realize that I can type in `until *0x8048eb8`, but what if I don't know what my next compare will be?

I have tried searching the web, but I haven't been able to find any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering `break *0x08048eba`.

Comment: I know that this just goes until the jump statement. I want to continue until the next, arbitrary compare statement though

Comment: So you want to break on any `cmp` instruction?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do

Comment: rbreak may get you part of the way there - though tbh I don't know if it works on asm instructions or just functions, nor whether you have access to the disassembled code (i.e. c)